# Address Sanitizer not detect leaks in struct`s field array

Tags: c, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I really need some help with memory leaks. I compiled `code.c` (shown bellow) with `gcc -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -g -std=c99 -fsanitize=address code.c` and run it, Address Sanitizer not detect memory leaks.

How to detect these memory leaks, please?

Here is my code (`code.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VAL_LEN 50

typedef struct SItem {
    //int val;
    char val[VAL_LEN];
} TSITEM;

typedef struct S {
    TSITEM *m_Items;

    size_t m_Allocated;
    size_t m_Count;
} TS;

TS *S_create() {
    TS *newS = (TS *) malloc(sizeof (TS));

    newS->m_Allocated = 50;
    newS->m_Count = 0;
    newS->m_Items = (TSITEM*) malloc(newS->m_Allocated * sizeof (*newS->m_Items));

    return newS;
}

void S_destroy(TS *s) {
    //free(s->m_Items);  ------>  commented intentionally: this may occur memory leak, BUT NOT DETECTED BY -fsanitize=address

    s->m_Items = NULL;
    s->m_Count = 0;
    s->m_Allocated = 0;

    free(s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {
    TS *s = S_create();


    S_destroy(s);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Netbeans compiles my code with `gcc -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fsanitize=address -c -g -Wall -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/tset.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/codde.o code.c`

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, in C you [don't need to (and reallu shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: As for your problem of detecting memory leaks, perhaps use something like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) instead? It's a good idea to use multiple tools.

Comment: I tried valgrind - used ´valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2´ (from https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.mcrun) and this has no effect. Valgrind prints this:

´´´bash
==8668== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
´´´

Comment: Then it's time to look at the generated code. With the code you show the compiler might "optimize" away the function calls. Try doing something using the structures between the create and destroy calls.

Comment: The same code compiled with the same gcc toolchain gives me a leak: _SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 2500 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s)._ What OS are you using?

Comment: OT: `m_Items`, `m_Allocated`, .... we don't need all those `m_` in C, since we can not ommit the member's parent, there is no room for ambiguities.

Comment: $ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I use: 
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I use IDE NetBeans

Comment: Netbeans compiles my code with `gcc -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fsanitize=address -c -g -Wall -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/tset.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/codde.o code.c`

Comment: Omitting irrelevant flags, [it should report the leak](https://godbolt.org/z/jETcfj).